# Optimization With Inactive Constraint

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider an optimization problem (P1):
$$
\min_{\textbf{x} \in X} \{ f(\textbf{x}): g(\textbf{x}) \leq 0 \} 
$$
where $f,g$ are convex functions over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. Suppose that $\textbf{x}^*$ is an optimal solution of Problem (P1) that satisfies $g(\textbf{x}^*) <0.$ I would like to show that $\textbf{x}^*$ is also an optimal solution of the problem (P2):
$$
\min_{\textbf{x} \in X} f(\textbf{x})
$$
without consulting the Lagrange multiplier approach.

**Below is my attempt:**
Let $\textbf{x}^*$ with $\textbf{x}^* < \textbf{0}$ be optimal solution for the problem $\min_{\textbf{x} \in X} \{ f(\textbf{x}): g(\textbf{x}) \leq {0}\}.$ We must show for all $\textbf{y} \in X$,
$$
 f(\textbf{x}^*) \leq f(\textbf{y}).
 $$
Let $\textbf{y} \in X$ be given. Consider $\textbf{z} := \theta \textbf{x}^* + (1-\theta) \textbf{y} \in X$. Then, by convexity of $f$, we have
$$
f(\textbf{z}) \leq \theta f(\textbf{x}^*) + (1-\theta) f(\textbf{y}) .
$$
In addition, by convexity of $g$ and the fact that $g(\textbf{x}^*)<0$, it follows that
$$
g(\textbf{z}) \leq \theta g(\textbf{x}^*) + (1-\theta) g(\textbf{y}) < (1-\theta) g(\textbf{y}).
$$
Now, if $\textbf{y}$ is such that $g(\textbf{y}) \leq 0$, then we have
$
g(\textbf{z}) <0.
$
Hence, by optimality of $\textbf{x}^*$ for P1, it follows that
$$
f(\textbf{x}^*) \leq f(\textbf{z})  = \theta f(\textbf{x}^*) + (1-\theta) f(\textbf{y}) 
$$
which implies $f(\textbf{x}^*) \leq f(\textbf{y})$, which is desired.

However, I fail to prove the case where $\textbf{y}$ is such that $g(\textbf{y})>0$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Assume for contradiction that $\exists y$ with $g(y) > 0$ and $f(y) < f(x^{*})$. Use convexity to argue that every convex combination $z$ of $x^{*}$ and $y$ evaluates to less than $f(x^{*})$. Choose this convex combination such that $g(z) < 0$ (which follows from continuity of $g$).  Since $f(z) < f(x^{*})$ this contradicts $x^{*}$ as optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [KKT conditions](http:///https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions), $x^*$ gives both stationarity and complementary slackness, i.e. there exists $\mu \geq 0$ (of dimension the range of $g$, which seems to be one here) with
$$\nabla f(x^{*}) + \mu^\, \nabla g(x^{*}) = 0$$
and
$$\mu \, g(x^{*}) = 0.$$

By your assumption you have that $g(x^*) \neq 0$, so complementary slackness gives that $\mu = 0$, which by stationarity gives that $\nabla f(x^{*}) = 0$. Since $f$ is convex we conclude that $x^{*}$ minimizes the unconstrained $f$.